# What's the difference between AutoCAD and AutoCAD LT?

Tags: autocad, dwg

Want to play with AutoCAD for personal use. Which edition is suggested?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are the [differences between AutoCAD and AutoCAD LT](http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/pc/compare/index?siteID=123112&id=13723825).

Answer (score 1):

AutoCAD is expensive software just for personal use.

I would definitely recommend LT over Full AutoCAD if its just to "play" with. There are only small differences if your main interest is 2D draughting, these differences do not justify the large price jump IMO.

Answer (score 1):

AutoCAD LT is a mutation of an ancient MS-DOS *draughting* program, while AutoCAD has 3D abilities tacked on as an afterthought.

If you are starting out with CAD, I would suggest you try learning a modern 3D parametric object based *design* program instead.  If you wanted to stick with the Autodesk lockin, try [Revit](http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/pc/index?siteID=123112&id=3781831) for construction or [Inventor](http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/pc/index?siteID=123112&id=13717655) for mechanical.